# CSS table border with multiple tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have two tables in one page. I want to border around one of them and no border on the other one. So I am using the id="". But it is still putting borders around both tables and I am not sure why. If I change table1 for no border, it will take away the border on both tables. Please give me any helpful link or advice. Thanks.

```css
table 
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#table1 td, tr
{
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#table1 th
{
    background: orange;
}

#table2
{
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<table id = "table1">
    <th> Header </th>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id = "table2">
    <th> Header </th>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your selector `#table1 td, tr` says only `td` in table1 then ALL `tr`, everywhere.

Comment: Please check this link:-http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp Maybe it will help you.

Comment: @Raziasultana that is where I started, but it doesn't discuss multiple tables with different borders ect.

Comment: Please check this link:-https://www.w3.org/wiki/Styling_tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change your selector at `#table1 td, tr`.
`#table1 td` will apply to all `td` in `#table1`, but `tr` will apply for all `tr`.

So set it to `#table1 td, #table1 tr` and it works.

```
#table1 td, #table1 tr
{
   text-align:center;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/jowocejobe/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Thanks for much, this was driving me crazy and I couldn't find anywhere that said to put the extra #table1 in front of tr.